# c# binding datagridview to datatable in form vs control

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

I have the following code:

```
        DataGridView lGrid = new DataGridView();
        BindingSource _bind = new BindingSource();
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();

        this.Controls.Add(lGrid);
        lGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;


        List<string> ColumnsNames = new List<string>();
        ColumnsNames.Add("ID");
        ColumnsNames.Add("NAME");

        foreach (string Name in ColumnsNames)
            Table.Columns.Add(Name);

        DataColumn col = Table.Columns["ID"];
        DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
        keys[0] = Table.Columns["ID"];
        Table.PrimaryKey = keys;

        lGrid.DataSource = _bind;
        _bind.DataSource = Table;

        int i = lGrid.Columns.Count;
```

which populates lGrid with columns in datatable just fine with this code executing in the form constructor. However, when I move it to the control constructor binding doesn't work and i = 0. Why is it so and what can i do about it?

## Update1

OK. the constructors are the most simple

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
          InitializeComponent();
         //CODE GOES HERE
    }
}
```

VS

```
public class mycontrol : Control
{
    public mycontrol()
    {
        //CODE GOES HERE
    }
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
          InitializeComponent();

          mycontrol ll = new mycontrol();
          this.Controls.Add(ll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Winforms/WPF/ASP.NET?

Comment: can you post the two constructors where the issue arises?

Comment: @Robbie this is winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use think if you

```
lDataGrid.Bind();
```

then you will get the Count()

or check the Count on the AfterDataBinding Event.

Comment: datagridview doesnt seem to have Bind method, but checking count in DataBindingComplete event indeed works, thank you. Can anyone please explain me why doesn't it bind straight away like it does in form?

Comment: Reason why is because your calling the Code on your MyControl class not on the Form Control. and If im correct your application start is not actually Binded yet. Someone might be able to explain that a bit better than i can. If you actually had the Control as part of the Form in the IntitializeComponent() Call, you would then get binding directly.