# Datagridview to datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to connect a dataGridView to a datatable but I cannot get it to work. Here is my code:

```
public void ToDatabase(string Database, string Table, DataTable Datatable)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM `" + Database + "`.`" + Table + "`;";
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Update(Datatable);
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}

private void buttonUpdateData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlBinding mb = new MySqlBinding();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = dataGridViewSql.DataSource as DataTable;
    mb.ToDatabase("SystemData", "SystemClientData", dt);
}
```

But I only get NULL.

I have read a lot of threads here and on other sites, and it looks like I should use a viewstate function to catch the data in the datagrid. But I just cannot really understand how and therefore I can't get it to work.

Comment: Since you've mentioned `Viewstate`, is it a n ASP.NET `GridView` instead of a winforms `DataGridView`? Where do you try to access the datasource, on postback?

Comment: Can you post the code, please?

Comment: Check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099673/c-sharp-binding-datagridview-to-datatable-in-form-vs-control

Comment: I have updated the question with the code im using. And i also checked the 5099673-link, but just cant figure it out.

Comment: And its a winform dataGridView im using. And could you please explain what you mean with postback? Im reading about this everywhere, and long as i understand, this is the problem. The problem is just that dont understand the real function of this...

Comment: Where exactly do you get the *null*?

Comment: Here: dt = dataGridViewSql.DataSource as DataTable; The dt never gets a data value... And what i can understand from reading a lots of threads is that it depeneds on the dataGridView returns no NULL after postback. But i cant really understand why, and how to solve it....

Comment: DataSource is just an object. It can be a list, for example. You have to initialize it first with an instance of DataTable and only later to cast it back, otherwise the result is unpredictable. And how do you expect to update the DB using *SELECT* command? Look [here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter.html) for the adapter usage.

Answer (score 0):

I know answering this question may end up doing nothing. There is a high chance that you don't understand how a `DataAdapter` works in `ADO.NET`. I just try posting this code for you to test, if it doesn't work, that means your code is **seriously** wrong:

```
public void ToDatabase(string Database, string Table, DataTable Datatable) {
  string query = "SELECT * FROM `" + Database + "`.`" + Table + "`;";
  if (this.OpenConnection()) {
     MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
     MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
     adapter.Update(Datatable);
     this.CloseConnection();
  }
}
```